# How to pass parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. In the stored procedure, I need to pass parameter to a select-where-like statement. For example,

@department is store procedure input parameter, its type is varchar(20),

```
select * from sometable where somecolumn LIKE '%@department%'
```

but seems my statement above does not work, any ideas how to pass parameter @department to like statement?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select * /*But don't use * in production!*/
from sometable 
where somecolumn 
LIKE '%' + @department + '%'
```

Answer (score 4):

You concatenate the strings:

```
select * from sometable where somecolumn LIKE '%' + @department + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable, it goes outside the quotes.

`select * from sometable where somecol like '%' + @department + '%'`

Or, more preferably, add the %s to the variable and just use it directly

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select * from sometable where somecolumn LIKE '%' + @department + '%'
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
select * from sometable where somecolumn LIKE '%' + @department + '%'
```

Comment: No it doesn't. This is not dynamic SQL

Comment: You are correct sir. It was my knee jerk reaction for doing string concatenation in SQL. Still have nightmares about some of the code I have seen. I removed the statement from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sometable 
where CHARINDEX(@department,somecolumn)>0
```

You can also use the CHARINDEX function.